# How to interpret this paragraph from an MNDA in context with Ohio law?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, non-disclosure, ohio

The following paragraph was included in a Mutual Non-Disclosure Agreement template between two technology companies.

> The Parties agree that the disclosing Party will suffer irreparable injury if its Confidential Information is made public, released to a third party, or otherwise disclosed in breach of this Agreement and that the disclosing Party shall be entitled to obtain injunctive relief against a threatened breach or continuation of any such breach and, in the event of such breach, an award of actual and exemplary damages from any court of competent jurisdiction."

I was wondering what the implications of this paragraph are in the event of a breach.

Comment: Please spell out acronyms for clarity. I think that by MNDA you mean "Mutual Non-Disclosure Agreement" but that is not the only plausible reading of that term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A court could order the breaching party to stop breaching and to pay an amount equal to the economic injury caused by the breach.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the section, does threatened mean that the disclosing party can take action if they have evidence of a breach? Or does it mean that the disclosing party can take action if they think a breach occurred?

Comment: @philm it means that the disclosing party can take action if they think that a breach is imminent for some non-subjective reason.

Comment: @ohwilleke Thank you for your reply. Would you be able to clarify "non-subjective"? Does this mean that the disclosing party can take action if they do not have evidence?

Comment: That would mean that they need some evidence, possibly indirect or implied from communications with the third party, or from non-response to a demand not to do so, for example.

Comment: "Exemplary damages" could go beyond the actual economic injury, no?

Comment: Punitive damages would be exceedingly rare in a straight breach-of-contract case. In Ohio, they're typically limited to double the economic damages.